# Yii model relationship, how is it important?

Tags: mysql, yii

It is my first time to use `yii` and unlike my old programming style, i notice that it use relationship automatically in its model.

```
 public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
            'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
                'tbl_post_category(post_id, category_id)'),
        );
    }
```

I'm not used in doing this MySQL relationship. my old programming habit is connecting/manipulating the data to the php program itself.. To clarify my question, is this `yii` model relationship important? if i dont use this method, will i encounter problems?

Comment: Relations are a feature to simplify work with related data and boost ORM features, for example making simple read related records avoiding to write many queries. if you don't use it, you have to do many things with related data "by hand", wasting ORM features of relations and related data. Problems? no more than your own db design, primary keys, indexes and constraints, under your own risk (ACID and referential integrity principles). P won't give any trouble.

Comment: Framework won't give any trouble.

Comment: did you find what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii relations are very useful and if you work with it you will see that it will make you do less coding and make your code more readable.

while it is so much used in Yii applications, if you don't use relations, you won't get into any trouble, it is supposed to help you code and develop faster.

like if you looked at Yii blog, you have relation between Post model and Comments model, and you could go like this:

```
$post = Post::model()->findByPk( $id ); // find one post
$allCommentsRelated = $post->comments; // just one line for all search query and instanciating models
```

BTW in relations, there are two type of loading:

- *lazy* loading (this is **default** mechanism)
- *eager* loading

you have to know your scenario, and choose one that suites that scenario best

Comment: ill give the points here to you... im just worried that if did not use relationship i would get into trouble.